# Configuring error.log on Centos 6.5 with Cherokee 1.2.101 running PHP site

Tags: web-server, cherokee, logging

I have a problem configuring error log for virtual host serving PHP web aplication on our internal network.
I was hoping to get output similar to Apache's but I get output like this:

> {'type': "error", 'time': "27/03/2012 16:37:59.270", 'title': "PHP Warning:  mysql_close(): no MySQL-Link resource supplied in /var/www/html/intranet/prijave/Forum/PrijaveIntranetInterniForumSegment.php on line 33
> ", 'code': "handler_fcgi.c:115", 'error': "42", 'version': "1.2.101", 'compilation_date': "Feb 21 2012 12:43:57", 'configure_args': " '--build=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' '--host=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' '--target=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' '--program-prefix=' '--prefix=/usr' '--exec-prefix=/usr' '--bindir=/usr/bin' '--sbindir=/usr/sbin' '--sysconfdir=/etc' '--datadir=/usr/share' '--includedir=/usr/include' '--libdir=/usr/lib64' '--libexecdir=/usr/libexec' '--localstatedir=/var' '--sharedstatedir=/var/lib' '--mandir=/usr/share/man' '--infodir=/usr/share/info' '--with-wwwroot=/var/www/cherokee' '--with-libssl' '--enable-trace' '--enable-backtraces' '--disable-static' 'build_alias=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' 'host_alias=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' 'target_alias=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' 'CFLAGS=-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic' '--build=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' '--host=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' '--target=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' '--program-prefix=' '--prefix=/usr' '--exec-prefix=/usr' '--bindir=/usr/bin' '--sbindir=/usr/sbin' '--sysconfdir=/etc' '--datadir=/usr/share' '--includedir=/usr/include' '--libdir=/usr/lib64' '--libexecdir=/usr/libexec' '--localstatedir=/var' '--sharedstatedir=/var/lib' '--mandir=/usr/share/man' '--infodir=/usr/share/info' '--with-wwwroot=/var/www/cherokee' '--with-libssl' '--enable-trace' '--enable-backtraces' '--disable-static' 'build_alias=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' 'host_alias=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' 'target_alias=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' 'CFLAGS=-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic'", 'backtrace': "/usr/lib64/libcherokee-base.so.0(cherokee_error_log+0xa0) [0x3971627770]\n/usr/lib64/cherokee/libplugin_fcgi.so(+0x5cf5) [0x7f1c1552bcf5]\n/usr/lib64/cherokee/libplugin_fcgi.so(cherokee_handler_cgi_base_step+0xcc) [0x7f1c155286dc]\n/usr/lib64/libcherokee-server.so.0(cherokee_connection_step+0x6b) [0x3971a0f10b]\n/usr/lib64/libcherokee-server.so.0() [0x3971a1a9cd]\n/usr/lib64/libcherokee-server.so.0(cherokee_thread_step_MULTI_THREAD+0x26a) [0x3971a1aeaa]\n/usr/lib64/libcherokee-server.so.0() [0x3971a1b5fa]\n/lib64/libpthread.so.0() [0x3970a077f1]\n/lib64/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d) [0x39706e5ccd]\n"}

I opted for "Apache compatible" Format on "Logging" tab of this particular Virtual server (cherokee-admin) but as I can see this is in "Access Logging" and not in "Error Logging" block.

What can I do? Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

right now, error logging cannot be configured. this is not uncommon amongst app's.

the two (2) best options:

1.) using the system logger you will find cherokee using the 'user' facility - OR -

2.) just write it to a separate file such as 'cherokee.error'.

then you can re-write it any way you want with a post-op app. if you use logging, do not have cherokee buffer the output since you are writing to a very fast socket and the logger consumes the file-writing overhead very efficiently.